# Zipping up JSON file in xcode

Tags: xcode, ios4

Any idea how to zip up files in xcode so that it can be sent to a server,when an iPhone app terminates?

Comment: An iPhone app doesn't normally terminate unless the user explicitly kills it.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Exactly.. The client wants some logs on the server in a zip file when the app goes to background or is terminated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Objective-ZIP](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/) (wrapper on ZLib and MiniZIP).

Easy to use, as it provides Objective-C classes, and it works on iOS.

Comment: Thanks! Will check it up and get back to you! :)

Comment: In Objective-Zip, it creates a zip file and add txt files to that zip file. What I want is create a JSON/txt file and zip it. Any ideas?

Comment: Creating a file and zip it is the same as creating a ZIP archive and adding a file to it.